# Not able to change the value of an input field out of a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an html page for invoicing where I have created a table with these columns : Serial No, Category Name, Product Name, Quantity, Unit Price and Amount. Here Amount = Quantity*Unit Price

Unit Price is fetched from mysql db only. When a user changes Quantity of a product, Amount is changed to Quantity*Unit Price, using onkeyup function in javascript. This is working fine.

But, I have kept a field name Total Amount, which is outside the table but with a unique id in the HTML doc, which is the sum of all the values in the Amount column. In the same onkeyup function on Quantity, I want to update that Total Amount. I tried to do so as below(although not exactly sum as of now but just the Amount value in the corresponding row), which is not working:-

```
 $(".qty").on("keyup", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    qty_val = $this.val();
    unitprice_val = $tr.find('.unit_price').val();
    amount = qty_val*unitprice_val;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.pricecalc').attr("value", amount);
    //$('#total_amount').val(amount);
    //$(this).find('.total_amount').attr("value",amount);
    //$(this).find('.total_discount').val(amount);
 });
```

and the table and field for total input is:-

```
   <!-- TABLE starts here -->
    <table id="my_table_id" name="billitems">
        <tr>
            <td>Sr. No.</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="clone_this">
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>
            <select style="width:150px;" class="gr" name="categories[]">
                <option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>        
                <?php 
                    include 'connect_my_sql_db.php';
                    $qry = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM category;";
                    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($res)){
                    echo ("<option value='$data[1]'>$data[1]</option>");
                }
                ?></td>
            <td class="sub_item"><select style="width:150px;" class="it_id" name="products[]">
                <option value="Select Product">Select Product</option>
            </td>
            <td><input class="qty" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="ex: 12.50" name="qty[]" value="0.00" required onkeyup="updatePrice(this.value)"></td>
            <td><input class="unit_price" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="ex: 56.50" name="unitprice[]" value="0.00" required onkeyup="updatePrice(this.value)"></td>
            <td><input class="pricecalc" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="will be calculated" name="calculatedprice[]" value="0.00" required readonly="readonly"></td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Add more items" id="more_items" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px"/><br>

    <span class="sameline">
            <label class="smalllabel" style="width:100px;">Total Amount</label>
            <input class="total_amount" id="total_amount "type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="will be calculated" name="total_amount" value="0.00" required readonly="readonly"></td>
    </span><br><br>
```

Comment: Instead of $(this).closest('tr'), use $(this).parent().child('.pricecalc') (for example) to specify the fields. To set the value of a field, you change val(), not attr('value',val), IOW _$(this).parent().child('.pricecalc').val(amount);_

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor, create a snippet WITHOUT PHP but with enough HTML to give us a [mcve] - there is nothing PHP/mySQL related in this question

Comment: Sorry Guys, I forgot to mention that the calculated amount in the same row was getting updated successfully. The only problem is with the Total Amount which is outside the table. As suggested by @Alive to Die, I will try using class instead of id of Total Amount input field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.pricecalc')[0].value = amount;
```

instead of:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.pricecalc').attr("value", amount);
```

Comment: What is the difference in result? .val(amount) is even simpler